# what type of message can a websocket send?

Tags: websocket

I am trying to use a websocket to send audio message, what type of message should I change the audio stream into so that I can use a socket to send? 
If I directly use a websocket.send(audio), I would get an error "DOMException", should I change it into binary data? and how?
I am totally new to program, so please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Websocket API and supports sending Blob and ArrayBuffer binary types.

If your browser supports [Mozilla's audio data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) then you can read out the data from an audio tag as an ArrayBuffer and send that. However, this API is unlikely to be standardized.

If your browser supports the Web Audio API (proposed by Google) then you can also extract an ArrayBuffer of the data and send that. The Web Audio API will likely see greater adoption. Here is an [intro to Web Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/). [This FAQ](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/01/Web-Audio-FAQ) has an answer that describes how to use the Web Audio API to read from normal audio/video tags.

**Updated**:

The [Aurora.js](https://github.com/ofmlabs/aurora.js) library mentioned in [this blog post](http://badassjs.com/post/25174050115/flac-js-aurora-and-the-future-of-web-audio) looks like it might be helpful in dealing with audio and binary data.

Comment: then how can I get the data stream from a existing audio tag, I mean, if there is already an audio tag with src, I wanna get the stream and add it to peerConnection, but can I do this?

Comment: The Web Audio FAQ I linked to has a question titled "HOW CAN I PROCESS SOUND FROM AUDIO AND VIDEO TAGS?" that shows how to connect to an existing audio tag using the Web Audio API. The getChannelData method on an AudioBuffer can be used to read out the raw PCM data as a Float32Array (ArrayBuffer): https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#AudioBuffer-section

Comment: Is stream the same with Audiobuffer? I wanna get the stream from the audio tag, what is stored in the audiobuffer? I am really new to all these things, so could you give me more information and explanation

Comment: Just updated the post with a link to aurora.js which might help answer your questions. I haven't done what you are wanting to do myself. Mostly I'm just aware of some of the resources. If you figure it out before somebody else posts an answer, then posting back here would be helpful to the SO community.